# Function constantly running in the background using threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, background-process, python-multithreading

I want the following function to run constantly in a loop to simulate random movement of stocks, while the user can use a menu, this means that it has to run in the background. 
I've tried to do this by using threading, but I just can't get it to work.
I'm using the code for a stock simulator, don't know if this is relevant though.

```
def stockPriceRandomiser(stockPrices):

    length = len(stockPrices)
    count = 0
    while count < length:

        ranNum = randint(0, 1)

        if ranNum == 0:
            loss = randint(90, 99)/100

            stockPrices[count] = stockPrices[count]*loss



        elif ranNum == 1:
            profit = randint(101, 110)/100

            stockPrices[count] = stockPrices[count]*profit

        count = count + 1
    time.sleep(20)
    return stockPrices

stockPrices = [79, 45, 1233, 67, 54, 5000, 7000, 6974]
```

Comment: What have you tired with threading? I don't see that above? What could you not get to work exactly?

Comment: I can get it to run with threading, but i wouldn't know to keep it repeating itself, which is what i want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - you need to provide something reproducible, that shows you've tired something. "I wouldn't know to keep it repeating itself" What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thread should sleep in a loop, not right before it terminates.
And it should leave the loop when a flag controlled from the main thread is set or reset. Here is an example:

```
# coding=utf-8
"""
> python stock.py
Press Ctrl+C to exit
[86, 52, 1197, 63, 62, 5165, 6481, 7338]
[86, 52, 1197, 63, 62, 5165, 6481, 7338]
[86, 52, 1197, 63, 62, 5165, 6481, 7338]
[101, 55, 1035, 66, 62, 4457, 7172, 6673]
[101, 55, 1035, 66, 62, 4457, 7172, 6673]
^CTerminating...
"""
from random import random
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import signal


def stock_price_randomiser(shared_data):
    while shared_data.threads_active:
        prices = shared_data.stock_prices
        for i in xrange(len(prices)):
            coeff = 0.8 + random() * 0.4  # from 0.8 to 1.2
            prices[i] = int(prices[i] * coeff)
        sleep(5)


class SharedData(object):
    """Represent an object that is shared between threads"""
    stock_prices = [79, 45, 1233, 67, 54, 5000, 7000, 6974]
    # As soon as this flag turns False all threads should gracefully exit.
    threads_active = True


def main():
    shared_data = SharedData()
    randomiser_thread = Thread(target=stock_price_randomiser,
                               args=(shared_data,))

    def handle_sigint(signal, frame):
        print "Terminating..."
        # We don't want to forcibly kill the thread, so we ask it
        # to exit cooperatively.
        shared_data.threads_active = False

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_sigint)
    print "Press Ctrl+C to exit"

    # Start the thread
    randomiser_thread.start()

    while shared_data.threads_active:
        print shared_data.stock_prices
        sleep(2)

    # Wait for the thread exit
    randomiser_thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

We launch a thread and pass an object that is shared. That object contains `stock_prices` list and a flag we use to tell both threads when to exit. One thread updates the list, another reads the list in order to display it. When a user presses Ctrl+C, we handle interrupt signal by resetting our flag that makes our threads exit on next loop iteration.

P.S. The code is for Python 2